# Data Cleaning in Python - replacing with NaN

Tags: python

I am working to clean a dataframe in pandas. The data shape is (142538, 20).I have dropped all blanks and duplicate rows in my data. The shape reduced to (135345, 20). I need to columns with invalid values with NaN, and then dropped the result, but I the shape stays the same, even though there are columns with invalid values.

Here is a sample code for replacing invalid values in a column:

```
df['last_name'] = df['last_name'].replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]',np.NaN,regex=True)
df['first_name'] = df['first_name'].replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]',np.NaN,regex=True)
df['country'] = df['country'].replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]',np.NaN,regex=True)
df['college'] = df['college'].replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]',np.NaN,regex=True)
df.dropna()
print(df.shape)
```

The df.shape is not changing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include a [mre] in your question. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953). Also do some debugging -- have you tried printing out the dataframe to see if the values you wanted to be replaced were actually replaced?

Answer (score 0):

The `dropna()` method doesn't modify the dataframe itself (at least the way you used it).

Try

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

or

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you Ami. That was helpful.